# Looking for a way to get a persistent windows process which can access a locally mapped shared folder

Tags: windows, process, permissions, active-directory, windows-services

Our software needs to access a shared folder in the network mapped locally (let's say to drive z:) for a windows user, has to persist after the user session is dead and must not request for the credentials for the windows account from the user. 
In order to get a persistent process I can use a windows service, but it runs with its own credentials and unless the user manually sets its logon it can't access a mapped shared folder, and AFAIK it's usually not a part of the AD so it has no access to shared network resources.
On the other hand, a regular process has access to the mapped shared folder, but it dies together with the user's session.
Does anyone have any idea what to do in this situation? I understand that allowing a process to access resources on behalf of the user without the user specifically allowing ןא can be a potential security threat, but maybe there is a solution I haven't thought of. How can I monitor a shared folder without asking for credentials?
 Thanks

Comment: mapped drives are associated with logon session *LUID*. if session terminated - mapped drive also became not valid from this point. so even if you will be have permanent process - shared folder not permanent - live only until associated logon session live

Comment: @RbMm, yes, the device map and network credentials are cached with the user's logon session, which is referenced (and thus kept alive) by the user's access token. So you can duplicate and impersonate the user's token to persist access to the mapped drive even after the user logs out.

Comment: @eryksun interesting. Can you reference me to how to replicate this token (preferably using C#)? Impersonating as the user sounds like a good way to go

Comment: @eryksun - yes, you right. we can call  `ULONG SessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

 if (SessionId != MAXDWORD)
 {
  HANDLE hToken;

  if (WTSQueryUserToken(SessionId, &hToken))
  {
   HANDLE hDupToken;
   if (DuplicateToken(hToken, SecurityImpersonation, &hDupToken))
   {
    SetThreadToken(0, hDupToken);
    CloseHandle(hDupToken);
   }
   CloseHandle(hToken);
  }
 }` from service thread, but logon session not terminated after this, until token will be not closed